# Bulk objects download in Amazon s3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, aws-java-sdk

In Amazon S3, I have created 1 bucket under that bucket multiple subfolders like
`<bucket_name>/<year>/<month>/<day>/files` (i.e.objects).

I want functionality where on request I can download bulk objects by year / month / day, all files in zip.

Is there any way I can do this by Amazon Java SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `MultipleFileDownload` method provided with the Transfer Manager library that provides **Multiple file download of an entire virtual directory**. The contents, however, is not zipped.

See: [MultipleFileDownload javadoc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/MultipleFileDownload.html)

Since your objects are in directories by year/month/day, you could use this method to download all files in a specific path. However, the files would not be zipped.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using [mc](https://github.com/minio/mc) tool:

`mc cp -r https://bucketName.s3.amazonaws.com/<year>/<month>/<day> backupdir`

it copies from S3 to the local directory `backup`

and then you can zip the `backup` directory by:

`zip backupdir.zip -r backupdir`